# Routing for REST style urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I wish to set up routing to allow the following:

```
/entity/id          //id is Guid
/entity/id          //id is int32
/entity/actionname  //actionname is string matching neither Guid nor Int
```

Simple, I thought, that's what RouteConstraints solve:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "entity/id:guid",
    template: "{controller}/{id:guid}",
    defaults:new{action="Index"});
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "entity/id:int",
    template: "{controller}/{id:int}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "entity/action",
    template: "{controller=home}/{action=index}");
```

where, I believe, the order matters: the more-specific matches have to come before the entity/action route, which would otherwise match everything.

But this does not work.

```
@Url.Action("", "entity", new { id = Guid.NewGuid() })
```

results in

```
entity?id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

instead of

```
entity/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

How can I fix it?

(I'm on asp.net Core 1.1, although I believe the question is valid back to MVC4)

Comment: What if you provide parameter "Index" instead of empty string "". Will it make any difference?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this isn't due to your routes, but instead due to the way that `Url.Action` works.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov : Hmm. Very good. Yes, Url.Action("Index", "entity", new { id = Guid.NewGuid() }) gives the right result, so if you want to paste in an answer you get the points. It's a bug surely? Using "" for action should result in the default action being used

Comment: @sleeyuen Yes it's about how Url.Action works but how it works has to be driven by the routing table. Does it not?

Comment: I cannot tell if it's a bug, maybe it is expected behavior. And maybe it will work as expected of you pas null instead of "". I will post an answer.

Comment: yes, null works as expected.

Comment: Interesting - will have to keep that in mind.

Comment: This is an interesting question, @ChrisFCarroll , purely out of curiosity, why are you using `@Url.Action` instead of just typing out the `<a>` tag your self? The new tag helpers seem to be a pretty good replacement of the older razor syntax.

Comment: It's for injection into javascript, not markup. But since you ask ---  it turns out the tag helpers behave the same as Url.Action(). If I put asp-action="" in, then it gives the same result as passing "" to the action; but if I omit the asp-action it gives the same result as passing null

Comment: @erik-philips : doesn't editing the technology out of the question title mean that a horde of PHP developers will fruitlessly arrive here?

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll I see, thanks for answering my question. That's interesting about the tag helpers too. I'll remember that one. Great question!

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll [This tag system works. You can rely on it to notify users who are interested in a tag about your question. Stack Overflow is optimized so that tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of the question. Users are guaranteed to view your tags, and will take them into account when answering your question.

**Therefore it is completely unnecessary to force tags into your question titles**.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/171858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will generate expected result if you pass action name `"Index"` , or pass `null`, as the first parameter.